# Mvc partial view reload or refresh

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

i have a view called Index with 4 partial view like _tab1,_tab2,_tab3 and _tab4 , each partial view has form fields including submit and cancel button, when i click on _tab4 cancel button i want to reload the same _tab4 partial view with form data cleared.

```
   <ul class="tab">
    <li class="active" id="tab1">tab1</li>
    <li class="" id="tab2">tab2</li>
    <li class="" id="tab3">tab3</li>
    <li class="" id="tab4">tab4</li>
</ul>


    <div class="tabbody" style="display: block; ">
        <% Html.RenderPartial("_tab1");  %>         
    </div>
    <div class="tabbody"style="display: block; ">

     <% Html.RenderPartial("_tab2");  %>            
    </div>
    <div class="tabbody"style="display: block; ">

        <% Html.RenderPartial("_tab3");  %>         
    </div>
    <div class="tabbody" style="display: block; ">

        <% Html.RenderPartial("_tab4");  %>         
    </div>
```

Each partial view has submit and cancel button

Comment: Can you add you code and tell us what was your try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark each of your divs with unique id:

```
<div id="tab1-content" class="tabbody" style="display: block; ">
        <% Html.RenderPartial("_tab1");  %>         
</div>
```

Execute some jQuery code on cancel button click function:

```
$("cancelTab1buttonselector").click(function() {

   $.get("@Html.Action("Tab1")", function(data) {

      $("#tab1-content").html(data);
   });
});
```

Where "cancelTab1buttonselector" is selector for cancel button in tab1. Do same for each tab.
You need to create controller's actions returning each tab content as PartialViewResult:

```
public ActionResult Tab1() 
{
     var model = ...get model...
     return PartialView("_tab1", model);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try just load ur partials to the wrapper with data check attribute

html:

```
 <ul class="tab">
    <li class="active tab" id="tab1" data-tabid="tab1">tab1</li>
    <li class="tab" id="tab2" data-tabid="tab2">tab2</li>
    <li class="tab" id="tab3" data-tabid="tab3">tab3</li>
    <li class="tab" id="tab4" data-tabid="tab4">tab4</li>
</ul>

<div class="tabbody" style="display: block; ">
        <% Html.RenderPartial("_tab1");  %>         
    </div>
```

jquery :

```
$(document).on('click','.tab',function(){
var tabId = $(this).data('tabid');
 if(tabId=='tab1'){
    $('.tabbody').empty().load('/Controller/_tab1');
}
if(tabId=='tab2'){
    $('.tabbody').empty().load('/Controller/_tab2');
}
if(tabId=='tab3'){
    $('.tabbody').empty().load('/Controller/_tab3');
}
if(tabId=='tab4'){
    $('.tabbody').empty().load('/Controller/_tab4');
}
});
```